# Strange issue with UIPanGestureRecognizer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add pan gesture to my view but I do not know why it does not want to work. Here is the code of my UIView:

```
    self.infoView = UIView()
    self.mapView.addSubview(infoView)
    infoView.backgroundColor = .white
    infoView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    infoView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    infoView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    infoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.moveInfoView(recognizer:)))
    infoView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

I'm defining it in my `UIViewController` as:

```
var infoView: UIView!
```

and my pan gesture method looks like:

```
@objc func moveInfoView(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                              y:view.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
}
```

I really cannot see my mistake. It seems everything is correct there but it seems I'm wrong. Could you please point to my mistake?

**UPDATE**

My constraints:

```
let constraints = [
        // InfoView constraints
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
        infoViewHeightConstraint]
```

where

```
let infoViewHeightConstraint = infoView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 112.0)
```

Comment: Your `self.mapView` property is an instance of which class if you don't mind me asking? Is it `MKMapView` or a `GMSMapView` (Google Maps) or something else?

Comment: @Pranay it's GMSMapView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with your view being a subview of `GMSMapView`. The map view already has a bunch of gesture recognizers added to it and the gesture recognizer callbacks are sent to the `GMSMapView` instance and not your subview. Although there is a `settings` property on `GMSMapView` which lets you configure the user interface settings for the map. Try the following code to enable gestures:

```
self.mapView.settings.consumesGesturesInView = false
```

There are also other settings you could customize there. Hope this helps